# Meaning of "Accept-Encoding : deflate, br" header for security

Tags: security, http-headers

One of the companies I work with suddenly published a request to always provide header "Accept-Encoding : deflate, br" in requests to their API, because this is a requirement from their security team. But they do not disclose the issue.

But I see no immediate use of this header, being provided from the requester side, for any security means. Can you think of any?